# ajax show 2 data request with onclick

Tags: javascript, ajax

hello i am still new on ajax i wanted show 2 data in different place.

here the code

```
 <li onclick="showPost(this.value);" value="*digit*" >lala</li>
```

the javascript

```
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        function showPost(hal)
        {
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("gallekanan").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;  
                }
            }       
            xmlhttp.open("GET","../wp-content/themes/koolfort/example.php?pal="+hal,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            showJudul(hal);
        }

        function showJudul(hal)
        {
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("eventjudul").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;  
                }
            }       
            xmlhttp.open("GET","../wp-content/themes/koolfort/example1.php?pal="+hal,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
</script>
```

when i running the code just the showJudul running and the showPost is Aborted.

Comment: First, don't use global variables, use `var`. Second, I'm thinking... =))

Answer (score 0):

Move showJudul(hal); just after document.getElementById("gallekanan").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

Comment: ok. it's works but showJudul doesn't response, but the param has value

Comment: You should check your example1.php why it's not returning any response.

Answer (score 0):

Try having individual control of each function rather than calling them one within another one.. ie.. have it as

```
<li onclick="showPost(this.value); showJudul(this.value);" value="*digit*" >lala</li>
```

and

```
<script>

        function showPost(hal)
        {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("gallekanan").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;  
                }
            }       
            xmlhttp.open("GET","../wp-content/themes/koolfort/example.php?pal="+hal,true);
            xmlhttp.send();

        }

        function showJudul(hal)
        {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    document.getElementById("eventjudul").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;  
                }
            }       
            xmlhttp.open("GET","../wp-content/themes/koolfort/example1.php?pal="+hal,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
</script>
```

Also try using try{}catch{} where you try to initialize xmlhttp - the function might give error if there is no such object available...

Comment: they are return right response. ID event judul show right response but Id gallekanan show response showjudul not showpost response.